Why do I have a memory leak immediately after forking?
I am trying to understand why I have a memory leak in the child process, immediately after calling fork().
As I understand it, fork both child and parent share memory spaces have same content.
Why would a memory leak exist in my child process in this case?
Is there something I should be freeing when I am in the child process?
Here is my code:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int pid;
    
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        int thispid = getpid();
        printf("Now in child process - this pid is %d\n", thispid);
        system("leaks a.out");
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Now in parent process\n");
    }
}

Here is the output in terminal. As you can see I identify the child pid and check the child pid for memory leaks.
➜  -- ./a.out  
Now in child process - this pid is 52953
You have access to multiple processes named a.out:
    a) 52952 ./a.out
    b) 52953 ./a.out
Which process? (letter or PID) b

Process:         a.out [52953]
Path:            /Volumes/VOLUME/*/a.out
Load Address:    0x10e5eb000
Identifier:      a.out
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  a.out [52952]

Date/Time:       2024-05-05 13:30:22.384 +0400
Launch Time:     2024-05-05 13:30:18.632 +0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G103)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/leaks
Analysis Tool Version:  Xcode 11.3.1 (11C505)
----

leaks Report Version: 4.0
Process 52953: 179 nodes malloced for 27 KB
Process 52953: 4 leaks for 4128 total leaked bytes.

    4 (4.03K) << TOTAL >>

      2 (2.02K) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fee0dd00040 [16]
         1 (2.00K) 0x7fee0e800800 [2048]

      2 (2.02K) ROOT LEAK: 0x7fee0dd00050 [16]
         1 (2.00K) 0x7fee0e801000 [2048]

Now in parent process



"As I understand it, fork both child and parent share memory spaces have same content." FWIW, I haven't done any C programming in decades, but I'm pretty sure that "same content" is right but "shared" is incorrect. It's a different process. It inherits file handles and such, but if you want to share memory, I'm pretty sure you have to do that on purpose, for instance as shown in this question.

When you fork, the parent and child process each get a copy of the memory that was previously just the parent's. They each have to free it separately. Behind the scenes, OSs tend to defer the copying until it's necessary, but the semantics remain the same.

You haven't allocated any memory, so there's nothing to leak. It's probably referring to memory allocated internally by stdio or system(). Ignore it.
